# What is the difference between "." and "->"?

Tags: c, pointers

I've grasped the concept of pointers using these symbols (`*` and `&`) for declaring pointers and getting the value(s) of them. However I do not know how to use `->` properly for pointers.

I'd appreciate it if someone could provide me a link with info about ( `->` ) or explain it to me.

Comment: you may want to tag this with the language the question relates to

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do the "->" and "." member access operations differ in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424079/how-do-the-and-member-access-operations-differ-in-c)

Comment: StackOverflow is not suitable for "tutor me in absolute basics" type questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of about 20 million questions, several of them asked today.

Comment: How can this be marked as off topic?  It's about a central feature of the core C language, not a tool, library, or offsite resource.  Yes, it's a duplicate; the solution is to get it marked as a duplicate, not pretend it's off topic.

Comment: I can't see anything that is off-topic here. Duplicate should be a real duplicate and not a similar question. This is a new user, come on - let things breathe.

Answer (score 2):

`a->b` means `(*a).b`.  When using multiple indirection, `->` can be considerably more convenient, as in `a->b->c->d`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you have a struct `foo_t`:

```
typedef struct foo_t
{
    int bar;
};
```

Now, let's create an instance on the stack and access `bar`:

```
foo_t foo;
foo.bar = 1;
```

When we have an object (as opposed to a pointer to an object), as we do here, we use the dot operator to access fields within it.

However, if we have a pointer to the object, we use the arrow operator rather than the dot operator:

```
foo_t* foo2 = &foo;
foo2->bar = 1;
```

If we have a pointer to a pointer to the object, there's no special syntax and the notation gets a little uglier:

```
foo_t** foo3 = &foo2;
(*foo3)->bar = 1;
```